# Magento1: Site Crash build in Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento1.9.2.3

Following situation:

We use Magento 1.9.2.3 and our site loses the connection very often. Especially after new uploads,It's not a Magento error it's just lost connection.
I contact our hosting provider and they told me there is a lot of traffic but that's not true. We have in average about 90 people shopping on our site.

Error log shows always this problem:

> AH01797: client denied by server configuration:
>   /home/morefash/public_html/app/etc/local.xml

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: have you even tried googling it?! took me 10 seconds: https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/1322-client-denied-by-server-configuration-appetclocalxml

Answer (score 0):

this error is configured protection in magento, access to this configuration file is always denied.

you probably have very limited shared hosting account or very bad server.

request all stats from your hosting provider to see who and how exceeds the limits.

also as a shop owner you must know your limits and hosting settings.